# How do you set up autocompletion and code suggestions in python shell?

Tags: python, python-idle

I saw the following coding gif, which depicts a user typing commands (e.g. `import`) and a pop up message would describe the usage for that command.

How can I set up something similar?[image: gif depicting python shell with automatic code usage]

Comment: You can get some autocompletion using  readline and rlcompleter in the standard Python shell on *nix systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the github issues in the repo of that gif, the video was taken using [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org)

Source: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/67

Answer (score 1):

Code editors like [`vim`](http://www.vim.org/) (with [`jedi`](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) or [`python-mode`](https://github.com/klen/python-mode.git)) or [`emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) and integrated development environments like [`pycharm`](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) can offer the same functionality.